# Nginx throws 502

Tags: php, nginx

The following `nginx.conf` throws a constant 502 error:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    set $root_path '/home/forge/mydomain.com/public';
    root $root_path;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I got this straight from the Phalcon website, but this throws an error. I looked at my server log and I noticed this error: `connect() to unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream`. I have too little knowledge of Nginx to know exactly what is going wrong here. Do any of you?

Comment: Nothing wrong with Nginx. There is something wrong with PHP5-FPM.

Comment: Did you restart nginx/php-fpm services with a user other than root?

Comment: Yeah, I did that. Really strange...